# Permute digits of a number using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to create a program which returns true or false according to whether or not a vampire number this is the code I've done until now :

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

uint fact(uint a, uint r)
{
    static uint primes[10] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23, 29, 31};
    if (a){ r *= primes[a % 10]; fact(a / 10, r); }
    else return r;
}

uint permute(uint number)
{

    // I don't know how to go permuting the numbers

     return check(a, b) ;    
}

uint check(uint a, uint b)
{
      uint v = a * b;
      if (fact(a,1) * fact(b, 1) == fact(v, 1))
         return 1;
      else
         return 0;
}

int main(void)
{    
    int number = 1260; //number vampire

    return 0;
}
```

The downside is that I dont know how to generate the fangs ¿Can anyone help me with this?. Everything should be using recursion nothing of loops

Comment: Yes, please explain; what's a vampire number? Do you mean [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VampireNumber.html)?

Comment: Also, this looks like homework...

Comment: @FuriousFolder: if that's what I am referring

Comment: Alan, what? Can you please give a link to the site which **does** give a definition of what a "vampire number" is?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_number

Comment: The biggest problem is I see is that your code doesn't do anything...your `main` creates a number and doesn't do anything with it..

Comment: I've been trying to write an answer that doesn't just TELL you how this works...this is almost certainly a homework question; why else wouldn't you be able to use a loop?

Is this homework?

Comment: you mention recursion, but none of the functions use recursion.